# Child categories appear as their parent when selected

Tags: entries, categories

In an entry, when selecting a child category, the parent is shown as the selected item. This prevents the use of any child categories. Any help would be appreciated.

**Use Case:**
[image]

**Selection Modal:**
[image]

**Selection within the Entry**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a limit of 1 set for the number of categories? Selecting a child category (Pacific Northwest) selects the parent as well, and if there is a limit of 1, then only the parent end up selected.

To work around this, you could model the regions with a structure rather than categories. Picking elements from a structure does not select the parent as well, so with a limit of 1 it would be possible to select Pacific Northwest.